# psexec run process as different user

Tags: windows-server, administration, psexec

Lets say I have two users:

user1 -- admin
user2 -- limited

and I need to start a remote process as user2.

I cannot use the limited user (user2) to start the remote process, since psexec requires the user be an admin in the remote computer.

I tried the following:

```
psexec \\server -u domain/user1 -p password -d -i sessionID runas /user:domain\user2 cmd /c command
```

but it did not work, I guess because runas needs the user2's password.

Is there any way to achieve this?